# Flask-SQLAlchemy: Trying to use query.paginate() in reverse order

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm following Corey Schafer's tutorials to make a basic Flask website with SQLAlchemy (flask-sqlalchemy). The website uses a database containing users and posts. Currently, I display the posts on the front page ordered from oldest to newest, but I want to display them in the reverse order. I know I can use *Session.query.all().order_by()*, but I want to use the paginate method to paginate the results, and I don't know how to do that.

My original code works fine using *Session.query.paginate()*, but I want to reverse the results.

Currently, this is how my code looks for the home page route:

```
@app.route("/home")
def home(page=1):
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    posts = Post.query.paginate(page=page, per_page=5) # this line right here
    return render_template("home.html", posts=posts)
```

This code works fine to display the posts in multiple pages, but I want to reverse the results of the query so that I can display the posts in reverse order. I know about the method *order_by()*, but I don't know how to use it and whether I can use it with the *paginate()* method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer is **yes**, you can use paginate after sorting your query with `order_by`. As per descending order, you can just pass the method `desc()` to your `order_by`.

For example:

```py
@app.route("/home")
def home(page=1):
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.id.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=5) # this line right here
    return render_template("home.html", posts=posts)
```

I used the columnd `id`, but you can sort by any column in your database.